# How to keep numbering and add text before a section?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

I'm using the package `titlesec` with a  `scrartcl` document class. I would like to have my sections formatted as :

> Lecture 1. Section name

right now I'm using the command

```
\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{13}{13}\bfseries\sffamily}{Lecture \thesection}{1em}{}
```

though it doesn't seem to produce the result I need. The numbering and label are simply ignored.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we can copy-paste to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. You can redefine the KOMA-Script command `\sectionformat` to insert the prefix `Lecture`:

```
\renewcommand\sectionformat
  {Lecture\enskip\thesection\autodot\hspace{1em}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[numbers=withenddot]{scrartcl}
\renewcommand\sectionformat
  {Lecture\enskip\thesection\autodot\hspace{1em}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\large}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]